# A JAVA solver for ODEs with boundary conditions (BVP)

Tags: ode, software-recommendation, java

I need to solve a system of linear first order ODEs with boundary conditions in JAVA. I was wondering if any of you know of a JAVA package with the capability of solving a boundary value problems? (i.e. a solver using finite differences or finite elements)

The type of equation I want to solve is of the following type:
$$
n''(x) = -D(x)n(x) + n'(x)/x \\
n'(0) = 0 \\
n(1) = 0
$$
Through substitution this equation can be transformed into two first order differential equations.

I know there is the ode solver of Apache commons but it can only solve initial value problems. I have also read about the numerical methods but would preferably use existing code.

Comment: Side question: why do you want to use JAVA?

Comment: I am implementing a module in an already existing code which is written in JAVA. I tested and solved my problem in python using scipy and now I want to port this to JAVA.

Comment: If you have a working version in scipy, you could use it through [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) with the [Jython Native Interface](https://jyni.org/).

Comment: If you have access to an initial value solver you could use the shooting method.

Comment: Thank you for comments I will try these ideas!